Deriving the Finite Rotation Formula (Rodrigues's Rotation Formula)
I am working on Derivation 12 of Chapter 4 on p. 181 of the $3^{\mathrm{rd}}$ edition of Goldstein's Classical Mechanics. The question, paraphrased for readability, asks:
In a set of axes where the $z$-axis is the axis of rotation of a finite rotation, the rotation matrix is given by
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{D} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{(\Phi)} & \sin{(\Phi)} & 0\\
-\sin{(\Phi)} & \cos{(\Phi)} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
where $\Phi$ is the angle of finite rotation. Derive the finite rotation formula
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{r}' = \mathbf{r}\cos{(\Phi)} + \hat{\mathbf{n}}\left(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\mathbf{r}\right)\left[1-\cos{(\Phi)}\right] + \left(\mathbf{r}\times \hat{\mathbf{n}}\right)\sin{(\Phi)}
\end{equation*}
by transforming to an arbitrary coordinate system, expressing the orthogonal matrix of transformation in terms of the direction cosines of the axis of the finite rotation.
I'm working the problem and there is quite a lot of tedious algebra using my approach, so I wanted to see if what I'm doing appears to even be a viable way to approach the problem.
It is clear that the new transformation matrix $\mathbf{D}'$ (such that $\mathbf{D}'\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}'$, since $\mathbf{A}$ maps from general coordinates to coordinates whose axis of rotation is the $z$-axis, $\mathbf{D}$ rotates about the $z$-axis, and $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ maps from the $z$-centric coordinates back to general coordinates) is given by
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{D}' = \mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
is the orthogonal matrix of direction cosines describing the new, general coordinate system. Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{D}' = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11}\cos{(\Phi)} - a_{21}\sin{(\Phi)} & a_{21}\cos{(\Phi)}+a_{11}\sin{(\Phi)} & a_{31}\\
a_{12}\cos{(\Phi)}-a_{22}\sin{(\Phi)} & a_{22}\cos{(\Phi)}+a_{12}\sin{(\Phi)} & a_{32}\\
a_{13}\cos{(\Phi)}-a_{23}\sin{(\Phi)} & a_{23}\cos{(\Phi)}+a_{13}\sin{(\Phi)} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}
Carrying out the remaining matrix multiplication, we obtain entries like
\begin{equation*}
\left(\mathbf{D}'\right)_{11} = a_{31}^{2} + \cos{(\Phi)}\left(a_{11}^{2}+a_{21}^{2}\right)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{align*}
\left(\mathbf{D}'\right)_{12} = &a_{31}a_{32}+\cos{(\Phi)}\left(a_{11}a_{12}+a_{21}a_{22}\right)\cdots\\
&\hspace{1pc}\cdots+\sin{(\Phi)}\left(a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}\right).
\end{align*}
None of these entries seem to be readily simplified using the orthogonality of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Is there some way of reaching the desired conclusion from this work, or am I wasting my time? If I am wasting my time, what is a better way to attack this problem? I also thought that perhaps rather than transform the operator $\mathbf{A}$, I could transform the axis of rotation from $\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ to $\hat{\mathbf{k}}' = \mathbf{A}\hat{\mathbf{k}}$, apply the unchanged operator, and then convert $\hat{\mathbf{k}}'$ back to the original coordinates.
